# Gin outputs to a file

Tags: go

I'm using Gin to make REST API server and Gin shows its output on a console like this: [Gin console example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0LF5.png)

I'd like to make gin's output to a file instead of console.

What I've found is below code from Gin/mode.go

```
// DefaultWriter is the default io.Writer used the Gin for debug output and
// middleware output like Logger() or Recovery().
// Note that both Logger and Recovery provides custom ways to configure their
// output io.Writer.
// To support coloring in Windows use:
//      import "github.com/mattn/go-colorable"
//      gin.DefaultWriter = colorable.NewColorableStdout()
var DefaultWriter io.Writer = os.Stdout
var DefaultErrorWriter io.Writer = os.Stderr
```

Looks like I can change DefaultWriter and DefaultErrorWriter's behavior by setting like

```
gin.DefaultWriter = something
```

on my code.

But I have no idea how to write that 'something' code; it must be a function which writes to a file but have no idea how/where to start.

So, my questions are:

1. Am I heading to the right direction?
2. How to write that 'something' function? It would be very helpful if you can provide an example.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to set it to an instance of os.File as returned by [os.OpenFile](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#OpenFile) with the according settings.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `os` package to create a file.

```
file, fileErr := os.Create("file")
if fileErr != nil {
    fmt.Println(fileErr)
    return
}
gin.DefaultWriter = file
```

This should create a file and start writing to it.

Comment: Thank you. It is working.Looks like Windows notepad cannot handle UNIX newline character, but anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try running your API via **nohup** command.

1. Run the build command to build your project.
   <name_of_project> can be anything

> go build -o ./build/<name_of_project>

2. Run the build project. <output_file> name can be anything

> nohup ./build/<name_of_project> > <output_file>.out

This will print all the log statements in the **.out** file.

Comment: Hi. The nohup command is not doing much in that case. The command only works because you are using stdout redirection (`>`). This line would do the job: `./build/<name_of_project> > <output_file>.out`